# Arbitrary Column Sizes And Missing Borders In IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have created nested tables with the following markup, where the first table contains an example of a typical row:

```html
<table class="outer">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="column" id="left_column">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="cell" id="t1">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="t1r2c0" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="t1r2c1" />
                                </td>
                                <td class="image">
                                    <span id="s1" runat="server">
                                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="p1" runat="server">
                                        </asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="t1r2c3" />
                                </td>
                                <td class="gray">
                                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="t1r2c4" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="cell" id="t2">
                            <!-- ... -->
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="column" id="rightColumn">
                <!-- ... -->
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the relevant CSS:

```css
#rightColumn table, #leftColumn table {
    width: 100%;
}
.cell {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
.cell td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.image {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 75px;
}
```

In Firefox this renders like this:

[image]

but in IE6 it renders like this:

[image]

Two things are going wrong in IE:

1. The right hand border is missing from every table.
2. The 2nd and 3rd tables in the right hand column have arbitrary sizes for the last column despite the fact that these cells are class "image" and should have a fixed width of 75px.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: #rightColumn table, #leftColumn table { width: 100%; background: Red }

[image]

Comment: Does adding `float: left` or `zoom: 1` to the style of any/all of the elements help?

Comment: Apparently not, but thanks for the suggestion.  "zoom" isn't even available in my editor. :-)

Comment: Can you post a link to a screenshot with `#rightColumn table, #leftColumn table {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}`?

Comment: See my edit to the post.

Comment: @Kevin - just because `zoom` isn't in your editor doesn't mean you can't try it... it's an IE-specific style, and setting `zoom:1` is known to fix a number of IE display glitches. I'm not sure it would work for this one, but don't rule it out just because your editor doesn't like it.

Comment: Can you post (another) screenshot of `width: 90%;` instead of `width: 100%;`? You can just post a link in a comment. (Stack Overflow uses http://imgur.com, you can go to that website and upload a screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Check whether IE is rendering your page is in quirks mode or not. Quirks mode often affects element widths in particular, so I would suggest that this is a very strong candidate for the cause of your problem.

You should make sure the page is in standards mode in order to render correctly.

This is easily done by making sure the page has a valid doctype at the top of the page.

If you don't have a doctype, you can add any valid doctype to get it working in standards mode, but if you're not sure which one to use, just use the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Hope that helps.